# Set slanted text for Google Charts (Material Bar chart)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, pygooglechart

Have tried the following:

```
hAxis: {slantedText: true, slantedTextAngle: 90}
```

However this only works for core charts

I once needed to set the title on the material chart and used this work around:

```
series: {
          0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
        },
      vAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: '# of Successes'},
      },
```

Wondering if the solution involves manipulating the code above

Comment: simply not supported, see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

Answer (score 0):

var options = {

```
      title: 'Nombre d emails par jour',
      hAxis: {title: 'Jour',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'},  slantedText: true},
      vAxis: {minValue: 0},
      
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).